# Mejor forma de modificar los valores de una lista de objetos

Tags: java, lista, bucle-for, foreach, collection

buenos días Comunidad,
Para modificar el valor de una lista de objetos e Java utilizo un foreach. Pero me preguntaba si habia otra forma más eficiente en Java.Collections u otra libreria de hacer esto.

Os pongo un ejemplo:

```
/* LibroList es una lista ya creada y con datos de los objetos (ID, ISBN, AUTOR)
   Libro tiene sus Getter y sus Setter creados.
   El string Autor siempre va a ser el mismo en todos 
los libros ya que para este caso quiero tener en todos los libros el mismo autor.*/

List<Libro> nuevaListaLibros = new ArrayList<Libro>;
for(Libro libro :libroList){ 
   libro.setAutor("Autor");
   nuevaListaLibros.add(libro);
}
```

¿Hay alguna forma de simplificar y agilizar este código modificando la primera lista (libroList) o creando una lista nueva pero sin llegar a usar un foreach para ello?

O sea, ¿Cuál es el método y la forma más rápida de llevar a cabo este tipo de acciones que es recorrer una Lista y modificar una serie de valores de esta lista?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Un saludo a todos y feliz año nuevo.

Comment: Puede hacerse con menos líneas de código (usando una lambda), pero en realidad no puedes hacerlo de diferente manera. Es decir, si lo que necesitas es recorrer la lista y modificar todos los elementos... puedes hacerlo de muchas maneras, pero todas van a implicar recorrer la lista y modificar cada elemento. Puedes usar un loop normal y hacer tu el recorrido y la modificación, o puedes usar `forEach` y pasarle lo que quieres que haga con cada elemento... pero en realidad en ese caso solo estás usando una herramienta que itera sobre tu array, exactamente igual que lo haces tu :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de la otra respuesta,aunque para lo que requieres habría que añadir un **addAll()** básicamente para copiar los datos modificados de libroList a nuevaListaLibros

```
libroList.forEach(libro -> libro.setAutor("Autor"));
nuevaListaLibros.addAll(libroList);
```

o podrias hacer uso de *peek*

```
List<Libro>nuevaListaLibros = libroList.stream().peek(libro -> libro.setMarca("Autor")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Fuente: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar Lambda expressions. Para tu ejemplo:

libroList.forEach(libro -> libro.setAutor("Autor"));

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Cuál es el método y la forma más rápida de llevar a cabo este tipo de acciones que es recorrer una Lista y modificar una serie de valores de esta lista?

Si bien las otras respuestas te muestran otra forma de recorrer la lista, considero que no contestan tu pregunta que en escencia es:

> La forma más rápida de recorrer una Lista

### Introducción

Ahora bien, para contestar eso hay que tener en cuenta el concepto de [eficiencia algorítmica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eficiencia_algor%C3%ADtmica) que, básicamente, es la cantidad de recursos que utiliza un determinado algoritmo.

En tu pregunta mencionas la forma más rápida, por lo tanto, cuando hablamos de `cantidad de recursos que utiliza un determinado algoritmo` nos centraremos en el recurso `tiempo` y no en `espacio` utilizado.

Bien, dentro del [análisis teórico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eficiencia_algor%C3%ADtmica#An%C3%A1lisis_Te%C3%B3rico) de la eficiencia de algoritmos, la complejidad de un algoritmo, recorrer una lista, está dentro la complejidad lineal `O(n)`.

Esto significa que el tiempo de ejecución del algoritmo depende linealmente de la cantidad de elementos del mismo (n).

### Respuesta

Por lo tanto, recorrer la totalidad de una lista, de principio a fin, te tomará por lo menos `n` ciclos, siendo `n` la cantidad de elementos de la misma.

En otras palabras, no hay una forma más rápida de recorrer una lista que elemento por elemento.

---

Ahora bien, puedes realizar esta tarea de recorrer elemento por elemento de forma paralela, es decir utilizando la máxima cantidad de núcleos que posea la computadora en donde se ejecute tu programa. Pero de esta manera, dependerás del hardware para que tu programa sea más o menos "rápido".

Puedes crear un `Stream` paralelo a partir de tu lista. Y dejar que la clase `Collection` se encargue del paralelismo por ti. Aquí te dejo la documentación de [parallelStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#parallelStream--)